# Where did the 'Use UV for Mapping' option go in Blender 2.8?

Tags: uv, interface, bezier-curves, versions, vector-mapping

I'm following a tutorial using a 2.7 version of Blender, which shows how to use UV unwrapping on beveled curves to make a texture follow the shape of the curve (I'm making stylized hair and would love not to have to convert it to a mesh.) However, the check box for that option under the "Texture Space" menu in the Curve Properties sidebar is not there in 2.8 like it apparently was in 2.7 versions. Here's where I'm looking, for comparison.
[image]
[image]
I've already looked everywhere in the program that I thought it might have been moved to. I didn't start using Blender until this most recent version so I know things have been moved around a little; I just can't find this one!! Thanks in advance!

Comment: All curves now create a UV map, same as they used to create with that option.  It's no longer necessary.  (There was never any reason not to enable it before.)

Comment: There was a reason, but I'm glad it's default though. If you converted to a mesh, there were no UVs when you didn't tick that box.